# Access Object Value Across Arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access an object value across an array, but its coming up as undefined every time. How can I have the array "terrain" use the "Dirt" objects variable such as SpawnChance?

```js
var terrain = new Array("Dirt1", "Dirt2", "Dirt3");

var Dirt1 = new Object();
Dirt1.Name = 'Dirt1';
Dirt1.Level = '1';
Dirt1.SpawnChance = '70';

var Dirt2 = new Object();
Dirt2.Name = 'Dirt2';
Dirt2.Level = '1';
Dirt2.SpawnChance = '15';

var Dirt3 = new Object();
Dirt3.Name = 'Dirt3';
Dirt3.Level = '1';
Dirt3.SpawnChance = '10';

if ($("#startingblock").hasClass("Dirt1")) {

  var blockcount = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 1) * 2;
  var blockcount = blockcount * blockcount;

  var i = 0;
  while (i < blockcount) {

    var randomizer = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1);

    var terraintypes = terrain.length;

    var terrainrandoms = (Math.floor(Math.random() * terraintypes) + 0);

    var newrandomterrain = (terrain[terrainrandoms]);

    var randomterrainspawnchance = newrandomterrain.SpawnChance;

    terrain.push(newrandomterrain);


    alert(newrandomterrain);

    i++;



  }
```

Comment: `"SyntaxError: missing } in compound statement"`

Comment: Very strange.  I'm not sure if `terrain` is supposed to be the list of terrain types, and then you're constructing a map where each cell in the map is one of the terrain types?  Because it's weird that you are pushing a copy of one of the existing terrain elements into the terrain array.  Can you explain your goal?

Comment: I am pushing the terrain types because the map tiles are meant to be randomized, based on the SpawnChance value. The goal is to iterate the loop based on the "chance" of a tile being spawned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the `SpawnChance` method on a string - eg. `"Dirt1"`. You want the objects themselves - so this is the source of the problem:

```
var terrain = new Array("Dirt1", "Dirt2", "Dirt3");
```

Just make it this instead:

```
var terrain = new Array(Dirt1, Dirt2, Dirt3);
```

(or better still:

```
var terrain = [Dirt1, Dirt2, Dirt3]
```

there's no reason to ever use the `Array` constructor rather than the literal form)

Note that you'll have to move it to later in the code than the definition of those objects.